# Android save logcat output in cmd to html to use them in excel

Tags: android, excel, cmd, diagram, logcat

I know how to log logcat output from my smartphone (by TAG) in cmd. But is there a way to save this outputs into a html file column by column? I log two values which I want to use for a excel diagram( one represents the x-value, the other one the y-value); that's why I need the columns...

thx & regards
PS : I have to use cmd because I log two devices at the same time !

Comment: You can only create a output file with  'adb logcat -d > out.txt' command.

Comment: Why HTML? It would be much easier to transform to transform logcat output to CSV and then import it

Comment: ok. But how can I transform the raw logcat output to the csv-format (add line-breaks, remove unnecessary chars,...)

Answer (score 0):

Why not incorporate SQLite3 into your app, write your output into a table and then save the SQlite3 database when your app exits? The use aSQLiteManager[free] to read and manipulate your data.